# How to add an item to the beginning of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

In the script below, I need to add an item "None" with value of "" to the beginning of the array.

I'm using the $addFonts array below to do that, however, its being added to the select menu as "Array". What am I missing?

```
$googleFontsArray = array();
$googleFontsArrayContents = file_get_contents('http://phat-reaction.com/googlefonts.php?format=php');
$googleFontsArrayContentsArr = unserialize($googleFontsArrayContents);

$addFonts = array(
'' => 'None'
);

array_push($googleFontsArray, $addFonts);

foreach($googleFontsArrayContentsArr as $font)
{
    $googleFontsArray[$font['css-name']] = $font['font-name'];
}
```

Comment: It's only showing as `Array` because you converted it to a string at some point - which none of the above code does... What do you want the resulting `$googleFontsArray` to look like?

Comment: array("" => "None", "Abel"=>"Abel", etc...)

Comment: You say `to the beginning of the array` but I suspect that the actual position in the array is irrelevant since you are making an associative array that looks like a lookup table. In which case, @Fox's answer below is probably what you want. Actually, if you pass `$addFonts` as the first argument to `array_merge()` and `$googleFontsArray` as the second it will be on the beginning anyway. The other point is that if the order is significant, you most likely want them in alphabetical order, in which case you can just [`ksort()`](http://php.net/ksort) it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should just be

```
$googleFontsArray['None'] = '';
```

This array is associative.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [array_unshift()](https://www.php.net/array_unshift).

Answer (score 1):

Add the first element in an array.

```
array_unshift() 
$sampleArray = array("Cat", "Dog");
array_unshift($sampleArray ,"Horse");
print_r($sampleArray); // output array - array('horse', 'cat', 'dog')
```

Remove first element from an array.

```
array_shift()
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to use

`array_merge($googleFontsArray, $addFonts);`

?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add one element to the beginning of an existing array, use array_unshift():

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php

Here is a complete list of array functions:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the addition operator:

```
$a = array('Foo' => 42);
$a = array('None' => null) + $a;
```

Note that most people would consider it bad practice to let the position of a pair be significant, when using associative arrays. This is unique for php - other languages have *either* vectors (non-associative arrays) *or* hashmaps (Associative arrays).